# Background App support

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have made an application in which alarms for various events are stored by the user. This app runs on both android and i-devices. So, the app raises an alarm when the event occurs. But if I close the application, obviously it doesn't remind me of the alarms. I want that even if the user closes the application, he should be informed of the alarm.

From what I understand, there are two ways this could happen.
1 -> Either run the application (using threads) in background.
2 -> As soon as user initiates any alarm, this gets stored in a database, and every time application runs and new alarms are installed, database keeps getting updated. But then again I have to make another app for database separately and that would be running in the background.

I just want to avoid it running in the background. Is there any feasible solution for it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an android question? Because this is easy on android.

Comment: The application is for both android and i-devices. Please let me know how is it feasible on android.

Comment: You can use services for this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Is there any solution for i-devices too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you can only run very specific background tasks.

Depending on when an alarm is needed you could use local notifications or push notifications, see: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)